Upload Files and Folders to Sharepoint using Excel VBA
I have an Excel utility that creates a file and folder structure on a local machine and writes logs to these folders.  The code uses Scripting.FileSystemObject to create the log files and CopyFolder to copy template folders to the destination.
I am looking to move the destination folder structure to Sharepoint and am wondering how to set my destination path so that the FileSystemObject will recognize it. It is Sharepoint online so I cannot use the UNC Path. I might be able to map a drive, but that would be a last resort.
Do I have to use the SharePoint API or Client SDK / CSOM? Will that work with CopyFolder, Dir() commands?
